# Change multiple column from float64 to int32

Tags: python, pandas

p/s I am new to python using Jupyter

Hi, I am try to convert the x,y,z, column dtype of float64 to int32
during getting the information, here is the result

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14640 entries, 0 to 14639
Data columns (total 3 columns):
#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
0   Lat     14640 non-null  float64
1   Lon     14640 non-null  float64
2   SSS     14640 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 343.2 KB
```

However, I don't have any clue on how to convert it into int32 for every columns. Is there any method to convert this multiple column of float64 to int32.

I really need any help from the experts on how to convert this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) following way

```
import pandas as pd
df_float64 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1.1,2.2,3.3],"y":[4,5,6],"z":[7,8,9]},dtype="float64")
df_int32 = df_float64.astype("int32")
print(df_int32)
```

gives output

```
   x  y  z
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Observe this will apply to all columns.

Comment: I tried your code however there is an error.

Comment: import pandas as pd
df_float64 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[:,0],"y":[:,1],"z":[:,2]},dtype="float64")
df_int32 = df_float64.astype("int32")
print(df_int32)

Comment: File "C:\Users\mniza\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11948\2538986876.py", line 2
    df_float64 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[:,0],"y":[:,1],"z":[:,2]},dtype="float64")
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @zam there are not `:` inside `[` and `]` in my code

Comment: Thus how can I call all the matrix for each column, since my data matrix (all columns) is in 14640 rows x 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

If you have several columns you can change it at a time with:

```
df[["A", "B"]] = df[["A", "B"]].astype(int)
```